# PhoneGap image capture and upload doesn't hit MVC4 controller

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cordova

I am attempting to upload an image captured with PhoneGap to an MVC4 controller and can't seem to get the file even though the PhoneGap application indicates success.

When I install this on my android phone and capture an image the message is updated with 'upload complete' but with a breakpoint in Visual Studio I dont see the file coming in and the file is not saved to disk. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Please see the following PhoneGap application.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Capture Photo</title>

   <script src='phonegap.js' type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
      var pictureSource;   // picture source
      var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

    // Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
    //
    document.addEventListener('deviceready',onDeviceReady,false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;      
    }

    function capturePhoto() {
      try
      {
          navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
            destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI});

      } catch(exc){
            alert(exc.message);
      }
    }

    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
      var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
      msg.innerText = 'got the image URI: '+ imageURI +' attempting to upload ...';
      try{
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey='file';
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType='image/jpeg';

        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = 'test';
        params.value2 = 'param';

        options.params = params;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, 'http://ipaddressofmycomputer/File/UploadFile', win, fail, options);
        msg.innerText = 'upload complete';
      } catch(err){
        var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
        msg.innerText = 'error from catch: '+ err;
      }
    }

    function onFail(message) {
      var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
        msg.innerText = 'Failed because: ' + message;
    }


    function win(r) {
        var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
        msg.innerText = 'Code = ' + r.responseCode +' Response = ' + r.response +' Sent = ' + r.bytesSent;
    }

    function fail(error) {
        var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
        msg.innerText = 'An error has occurred: Code = ' = error.code;
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick='capturePhoto();'>Capture Photo</button> <br>
    <div id='msg'>Waiting for capture</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The following code is the MVC4 controller action.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadFile()
{

    HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;

    bool fileSaved = false;

    foreach (string h in files.AllKeys)
    {
        if (files[h].ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string fileName = files[h].FileName;
            int fileSize = files[h].ContentLength;

            string serverPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/ImageUploads"));

            if (!Directory.Exists(serverPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(serverPath);
            }
            //Get & Save the File
            Request.Files.Get(h).SaveAs(serverPath + fileName);
            fileSaved = true;
        }
    }
    return Json(new { FileSaved = fileSaved });
}
```

Comment: You are calling `http://ipaddressofmycomputer/File/FileUpload` but your action's name is UploadFile. If you are using default routing, I also hope your controller's name is File

Comment: You have a very keen eye my friend. I updated the PhoneGap app with the correct route but sadly with the same result. Why wouldn't this cause the filetransfer to fail?

Comment: If you are still having problems, the first thing to do is to check what's the error message on your javascript side. In your front end application i see you catch the error, so what's the message? If it is 404 then it still must be routing issues, or firewall issues. Anyway that message would be helpful in debugging.

Comment: I agree an error would be helpful but unfortunately there is no error. It indicates success.