# Can't upload picture using phonegap/cordova to server on ios 7

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm using phonegap 3.3 and when I try to upload the upload the picture to server via file transfer plugin, I'm getting error 3 and http-status 500 on ios 7, on android it's working perfectly with no problem.

my client code:

```
    function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    $.mobile.loading('show');
      try{
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey='file';
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType='image/jpeg';

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, path + "/Home/postPicture", win, fail, options);
      } catch(err){
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
            alert(err);
      }
}

function win(data) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data.response);
    $("#PictureSource").val(obj.PictureSource);
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
}

function fail(error) {
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
    alert("error " + error.code);
}

function onFail() {
    navigator.notification.alert(
        'שגיאה לא ידועה...נסה שנית!',  // message
        alertDismissed,         // callback
        'שגיאה',            // title
        'אישור'                  // buttonName
    );
}
function selectInput() {
    navigator.notification.confirm(
    'בחר את מקור התמונה',  // message
    onSelect,                  // callback to invoke
    'בחירת מקור',            // title
    'מצלמה,גלריה, ביטול' // buttonLabels
    );
}

function onSelect(input) {
    switch(input)
    {
        case 1:
            {
                var destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
                var sourceType = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
                navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
                    quality: 50,
                    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
                    //correctOrientation: true,
                    sourceType: sourceType.CAMERA
                });
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            {
                var destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
                var sourceType = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
                navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
                    quality: 50,
                    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
                    sourceType: sourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY 
                });
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            alertDismissed();
            break;
        default:
            alertDismissed();
    }
}

function alertDismissed() {
    // do nothing
}
```

and my server side in ASP.net MVC 4 is pretty much the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202961/phonegap-image-capture-and-upload-doesnt-hit-mvc4-controller) (I have chekced it, and it working with no problem on android).

Please help,

**Update:**

when I'm trying to upload image from gallery it does work on ios, but taking picture and uploading it doesn't work, do you thine is a phonegap/cordova bug? or it's something else?